# Sonar scanner failer on force language to Kotlin

Tags: sonarqube

```
NFO: Source paths: .
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3.659s
INFO: Final Memory: 12M/134M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'Kotlin'
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm getting above error message when I forcefully set the `sonar.language=Kotlin`.
But when I turn off the `sonar.language=Kotlin` property code will automatically scan for Kotlin and XML files.

As on the image I have already installed Kotlin plugin to my Sonar server.

There for can someone please give me a solution to resolve this error.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to force the SonarQube to set the language to Kotlin??

As I remembered, the `sonar.language` is somewhat deprecated (correct me if I am wrong). 
Right now, it will automatically detect the language that you are using. That's why when you try to remove the `sonar.language` in your configuration and build again, it should work.